# Remove attributes from html string - error with removeAttributeNode

Tags: javascript, html, dom, attributes

I am trying to remove all attributes except for certain whitelisted ones from a long html string. I am using the DOM to parse it.

I know there are a lot of other questions about this, but my question is specifically about the error I am getting with executing `removeAttributeNode` in my code below.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<p class=\"p\">text here</p> <div id=\"divId\"></div>';
var elements = div.getElementsByTagName('*');
var whitelist = ["src", "width", "height"];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     if (elements[i].attributes.length !== 0) {
        var attr = elements[i].attributes;
        for (var j = 0; j < attr.length; j--) {
            var attrName = attr[j].name;
            for (var k = 0; k < whitelist.length; k++) {
                if (attrName !== whitelist[k]) 
                   elements[i].removeAttributeNode(attr);
            }
        }
     }
}
```

But, I keep getting the following error: `Failed to execute 'removeAttributeNode ' on Element: the 1st argument provided is either null, or an invalid Attr object.`

But, I checked with console statements and elements[i] is not null. For example, elements[0] = `<p class="p">`. How do I get `removeAttributeNode` to work? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `removeAttributeNode(attr)` should probably be just `removeAttribute(attrName)`

Comment: removeAttributeNode takes attributeNode as parameter. Element.attributes is just a named collection of attribute nodes but not the node itself. Try getAttributeNode(attrs[i].name) to loop through nodes and then remove them.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ckAmq7zuXxShlNTgKoUC?p=preview

Comment: @dandavis thanks! removeAttribute seems to work and doesn't throw an error. But the result elements is a HTML array. How can I get the string <p>text here</p><div></div> now that the attributes are removed?

Answer (score 0):

In the last loop, do something like this.

```
for (var k = 0; k < whitelist.length; k++) {
                if (attrName !== whitelist[k])
                 { 
                   elements[i].removeAttributeNode(elements[i].getAttributeNode(attrName ));
                 }
 }
```

Comment: For some reason `removeAttributeNode` doesn't seem to work. It gives an error that elements[i] is not an attribute. But, `removeAttribute` seems to work. But, `removeAttr` returns an HTMLCollection Array? How can I get the string without the attributes returned as follows:  `<p>text here</p><div></div>`